# Private composer package refuses to update

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

At work, I have a GitLab setup as a Git repository to host a common composer package that can and will be used across multiple sites (a symfony2 bundle for what it's worth).  Not a totally uncommon practice.

I managed to configure the composer.json's to see eachother:

On the site im working on right now, I have:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "coresystem/tools-bundle",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "{sorry this is private}",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-0": {
                    "CoreSystem\\ToolsBundle": "src"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and on the packages repository:

```
{
    "name": "coresystem/tools-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "description": "A collection of common use tools across the network of core sites",
    "license": "DBAD",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Kyle Harrison",
            "email": "{private, sorry}"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "CoreSystemToolsBundle": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

On the site, when I ran `$ composer require coresystems/tools-bundle dev-master` it worked just fine. It downloaded the repo, installed it. everything was great.

Until I needed to update the tools bundle.

I made my changes, and pushed them to the tools gitlab repo.

But on the site, when I ran `$ composer update coresystems/tools-bundles` it says there was nothing to update.

Out of desperation I started setting up some tags, pushing those, and trying things like `$ composer update coresystems/tool-bundle 1.*@dev` and such, to no avail.

In order to get it to work, i had to run `$ composer remove coresystems/tools-bundle` first, and then run `$ composer require coresystems/tools-bundle dev-master` again for it to reclone the repository

What gives?

Comment: Show us the `require` definition from your **composer.json** and also what is the output of `git branch` and `git tag` for your bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `type:package` as the repository description. This is too much manual work to be done, because Composer can detect everything it needs to know if you are using a supported repository (SVN, Git, Mercurial) and have committed a `composer.json` file into it.

Simply give Composer the location of the repository by using:

```
"repositories" : [
    { "type":"vcs", "url":"your private URL of the Git repo"}
]
```

This is all. No need to duplicate the autoload definition, or anything else that is required to be mentioned in the package description.